# BibTeX, hyperref, natbib and very long (institutional) author names in references

Tags: hyperref, bibtex, line-breaking, natbib

Edit: having tried to make a MWE the issue I was having has gone away - so please disregard!

I'm having trouble with a reference to a work by MIT, I *have* to cite this as "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (yyyy)" (I've checked, "MIT (yyyy)" is not acceptable).  In any case, the only ways I can find to prevent BiBTeX mangling the name (to "Technology, M. I. (YYYY)" in the references list and "Technology (yyyy)" in the citation) are to do one of the following in my `.bib` file:

1a) `author = {{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}}`,

1b) `author = {\mbox{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}}`,

2) `author = {Massachusetts Institute of Technology,\ }`,

However, 1a/b, prevent correct line breaking by `hyperref` as they create a single token, and 2, gives a reference list of "Massachusetts Institute of Technology, (yyyy)" instead of "Massachusetts Institute of Technology (yyyy)" (additional comma between name and year).

I can post a MWE if required, but hopefully the above description is enough to convey what's going on.  I've been right through the BibTeX and `natbib` documentation, but I just can't find an answer to this!

Comment: A MWE with regard to case 1a) and incorrect line breaking would indeed be helpful.

Comment: I feel as though I'm going slightly insane - I've just tried to create a MWE, but I couldn't.  And now I've gone back to my original document and that's working too.  What have I spent the last 3 hours trying to work out!?  Thanks for taking the time to read my OP.

Comment: Anyway, it works now. ;-) We'll probably close this question as "too localized".